# Cannot reach spring-boot-starter-parent dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I'm using https://start.spring.io/ to create Spring Boot project and in development I can't reach spring boot starters these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I get warning messages:

```
Overriding managed version 5.3.1 for spring-oxm
Overriding managed version 5.3.1 for spring-oxm
Duplicating managed version 4.5.13 for httpclient
Duplicating managed version 1.5.2 for saaj-impl
```

I've searched for how to fix it, one of the workaround some people refers to use `<!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->` at the end of the `</version>` tag to ignore the warning.

My question is how to make these (and other future dependencies) be seen from spring boot?

EDIT #1: pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>xx.xx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyyy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>yyyy</name>
    <description>zzzzz</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>

        <apache.cxf.version>3.4.1</apache.cxf.version>
        <apache.httpcomponents.version>4.5.13</apache.httpcomponents.version>
        <jaxb2.maven2.version>0.14.0</jaxb2.maven2.version>

        <springframework.version>5.3.2</springframework.version>
        <springframework.ws.version>3.0.10.RELEASE</springframework.ws.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb2.maven2.version}</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-support</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.ws.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.httpcomponents.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add your pom.xml.

Comment: Those are managed by Spring Boot but you are overriding them. You don't need the spring-oxm and spring-ws dependencies but rather the `spring-boot-starter-webservices`  dependency and those will be added automatically.

Comment: @tgdavies added edit

Comment: You're explicitly giving versions for dependencies which appear in the depenedencyManagwement section of the parent pom.

Comment: @tgdavies that fixes my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to remove `<version>...</version>`, let Spring boot handle the versions.

Thanks to tgdavies.